# Computing limits in PHP

Tags: php, limits, pow, infinity

I want to compute n^(2/3) as n approaches infinity in PHP.

What I tried:

> $n = "INF";
>   echo pow($n, (2/3));

Desired result:

> INF

Actual result:

> 0

Any suggestions? How to compute limits in PHP?

UPDATE:

OK, first problem solved - I just needed to remove the quotation mark.
But is this actually the way to calculate a limit? Is it interpreted as a limit?

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate - that's another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in the string "INF" into the [exponential expression](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php), which isn't valid. Try passing in just `POW`:

```
$n = INF;
echo pow($n, (2/3));
// INF
```

Comment: That actually solved the problem! Is that interpreted as a limit in PHP?

Comment: INF is the constant used when a number is too large for PHP. You can, though check `pow(INF, 0)` and see that it resolves to 1 correctly. In addition, `pow(INF, -1) == 0` is true